# Webpack, how to take out module into his own build layer?

Tags: build, webpack, commonschunkplugin, front-end-optimization

[image]

With default build settings I get following build layers:
(X+A), (Y+A+B), (Z+B).

I want: 
(X+A), (Y+A), Z, B

B should load only once when we asking Y and Z modules.

I found `CommonsChunkPlugin`, but I cant configure it properly.

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var CommonsPlugin = new require("webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: "./main"
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: [
            "."
        ]
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: "js/",
        filename: "[name].builded.js"
    },
    plugins: [
           new CommonsPlugin({
            //  What should I write here?
            })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Where to find the documentation about the definition of "layer" in your post?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should add `B` as separate entry point:

```
entry: {
   main: "./main",
   Bentry: ["B"]
},
```

and add CommonsChunkPlugin in `plugins` section:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('Bentry', 'B.js'),
```

Comment: tried, got an error "a dependency to an entry point is not allowed"

Comment: Sorry, `Bentry` must be an array. Edited my answer.

Comment: now I got common chunk B, but I have modules (Y+A+B), (Z+B) and have not any benefit from this common chunk. I need to exclude code of module B from parent build chunks sowehow